# In android, how can i turn off the screen programatically?

Tags: android, screen

I am trying to turn off my screen programatically.

The following methods i have tried:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.screenBrightness = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

The previous mentioned method does not work.

This however, works:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

mDPM.lockNow();
```

This works, but i am turning my screen off while the phone is ringing, and this causes the ringer to stop ringing. The same as if you are pressing the power button.

Well, i need to be able to turn off my display WITHOUT using DevicePolicyManager method. Or a way to set it that DevicePolicyManager method won't stop my device from ringing.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

its better to decrease the screen time out time to turn the screen off .
like this :

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

10 means 10 ms you can set your own !

Comment: That does not work as if there is a wake lock active then it will never time out. The `DevicePolicyManager` method i mentioned above is the proper way to turn off a display, just doesn't work perfectly in my situation.

Comment: but his not work for every devices . in my idea the best way is [here](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html)

Comment: That link you posted is exactly what i just said.. i don't understand what you are trying to say? So long as your device is 2.2 (API 8) or newer, you can use `DevicePolicyManager` and `mDPM.lockNow()` to turn off your screen.