# Turn the screen in to totally dark when press the button on the screen

Tags: android, screen, wakelock, powermanager

How to code the android to turn the screen completely off just like you press the power button to lock your screen.

I want the user to press the button on the screen and then screen goes off.

I have tried (with permission):

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
```

wl.acquire();

but not working for me, please help! thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679455/in-android-how-can-i-turn-off-the-screen-programatically

Comment: u just want to turn off the screen or also lock it?

Comment: just turn off the screen not the lock it.