# Screen goes off when Press a button,Android

Tags: android

I want the user to press the button on the screen and then the screen goes completely off, and if possible, the screen can turn on again within defined time.

I don't want to lock the phone but just like you having the phone call, and if your face placed close enough to your phone, the screen will go totally dark.

Please help,Thanks

[image: flowchart]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn the screen in to totally dark when press the button on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432552/turn-the-screen-in-to-totally-dark-when-press-the-button-on-the-screen)

Comment: yes, I still can't get the right answer.